# Using Powershell's invoke-webrequest to login to a server (Nexpose Security Console)

Tags: forms, powershell

I'm attempting to login to a webserver (via powershell) in order to create a valid (authenticated) session. The thought is to use that session to access links to reports that are only accessible when you are logged in. The issue is trying to login. Looking at the webserver's log, the user has never logged. Thank you! Sincerely, Feeling Powerless in Powershell

```
#Build Vars, later on take as parameters for a function
$server = '192.168.1.1'
$port = '3780'
$uri = "https://${server}:${port}/login.jsp"
$username = "user"
$password = "password"

#Make Webrequest to get session, and form
$nxCon = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -SessionVariable svNex
$form = $nxCon.Forms[0]
$form.fields #returns: "screenresolution, nexposeccusername, nexposeccpassword, login_button"
$form.Action #returns: empty
$form.Method #returns: "get"

#Fill out Form
$form.fields['nexposeccusername'] = $username
$form.fields['nexposeccpassword'] = $password
#$form.fields['login_button'] =
#above: Form has this field, filled with "Log on" by default. In other iterations I've tried setting this to $true.  

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($uri + $form.Action) -WebSession $sNex -Method $form.Method -Body $form.fields
#above: Since form.action is empty, it will be the same URL, but included it anyway.


#Returned data:
$response 
<# Returns Below: 
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                    <html>
                       <head>
                          <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" ></...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
                    ...

$response.Content
<#     ...
     <div class="alert-container">
        <div id="authErrorMsg" class="alert login-alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="display:none;"><p>One or more authentication serv
            ices are unavailable.</p></div>
        <div id="siloErrorMsg" class="alert login-alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="display:none;"><p>Login scope required.</p></div>
        <div id="invalidErrorMsg" class="alert login-alert alert-error" role="alert" style="display:none;"><p>The user name or password is invalid.</p></div>
        <div id="serverMsg" class="alert login-alert alert-error" role="alert" style="display:none;"><p>Your browser failed to contact the Security Console.</p></div>
     </div>

     <div class="login-header"></div>
     <div class="login-main">
        <div class="loginContent">
           <div class="loginBoxDiv" id="loginBoxDiv">
              <div class="loginContentDiv">
                 <p>Log on</p>
                 <form id="login_form" name="login" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="hidden" name="screenresolution" id="screenresolution" value=""/>
                    <div id="siloSelect" class="form-group"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="nexposeccusername">Username</label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nexposeccusername" name="nexposeccusername" autofocus="true" maxlength="255"></input>
                    </div> ...
```

Comment: You are not submitting the form. You are just reloading the page with session variables.
It might be good to look at what the post is and copy that into powershell.

Comment: Anyway you could post the headers you received. I have never seen a login done by a get before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open developer console in your browser. (F12 in Google Chrome, for instance)
2. Start capturing network traffic.
3. Login manually.
4. Look and the request, it's probably POST and in the details you'll see which parameters are transmitted.
5. Forget filling out forms, make a POST request directly using the same parameters.

Here's how I login into our internal website:

```
$Username = 'YOUR_USERNAME'
$Password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
$Url = 'http://www.example.com/'
$Body = @{'txtUserName' = $Username; 'txtPassword' = $Password; 'btnLogin' = 'Login'}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -SessionVariable VariableName -Method 'POST' -Body $Body
```

That's it.